# DBContext generated in controller, still getting The relationship between the two objects ... different ObjectContext objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dbcontext

I know there's a lot of questions with answer on this topic, but I cant seem to find anything relating to my scenario.

Im getting "The relationship between the two objects cannot be defined because they are attached to different ObjectContext objects" on `Inventory CurrentInventory = db.Inventories.Find(injection.InventoryID);`

This worked the very first time i ran it and subsequent attempts all fail.

I'm not understanding how the I'm getting different context objects.

My Controller:

```
public class InventoriesController : Controller
{
    private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

    // GET: Inventories/Edit
    public ActionResult Edit()
    {
        return View(db.Inventories.ToList());
    }

    // POST: Inventories/Edit/5
    // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
    // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit(List<Inventory> inventory)
    {
        //List<Inventory> inventory
        if (inventory == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        foreach (Inventory injection in inventory)
        {
            Inventory CurrentInventory = db.Inventories.Find(injection.InventoryID);
            CurrentInventory.Date = DateTime.Now;
            CurrentInventory.Quantity = injection.Quantity;
            CurrentInventory.LastChangedBy = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
        //  db.Entry(inventory).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(EntityState.Modified);
    }
}
```

EDIT:

I went back to a more single updating methodology just to see if that would help. I was STILL getting the same error. So I compared it with one of my other controllers modified Edit methods and noticed that I did not utilize the .Find() method instead I iterated over them records myself and returned the desired object. When doing do the problem was resolved.

```
// GET: Inventories/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Inventory inventory = db.Inventories.Find(id);
            ViewData["Id"] = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

            if (inventory == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(inventory);
        }

        // POST: Inventories/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "InventoryID,Quantity,LastChanged,Date")] Inventory inventory)
        {
            Inventory oldInventory = null;
            foreach (var a in db.Inventories)
            {
                if (a.InventoryID == inventory.InventoryID)
                {
                    oldInventory = a;
                }
            }

            if (oldInventory == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //db.Entry(inventory).State = EntityState.Modified;
                TryUpdateModel(oldInventory);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(inventory);
        }
```

Follow-up question:

Does the .Find() method create another dbContext in its implementation so that returned objects are inherently from a different context entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterating over the private context in the controller and returning the object needed instead of using the .Find() method solved my problem although I'm not too keen on the reason.

Comment: You shoud do Inventory CurrentInventorydb.Inventories.Find(x=>x.InventoryID ==injection.InventoryID);